# Updating with the mobile data

Tags: lumia, update, cellular-data

I reside in a district called Dhemaji in Assam, India. This is a small district where there is no Wi-Fi connection nearby. Now I own a Nokia Lumia 625 which shows that there is an update for the phone and asks me to connect to a wi-fi. But as there's no wifi near my place, I want to get the update using the 3G mobile data on my phone but failed everytime I tried to. Please help me to update the phone software using 3G mobile data. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a computer/laptop? If so, what operating system?

Comment: Do you have access to a 3G dongle that can broadcast wifi?

Comment: Contact nearest Nokia Care Center.

Comment: Yes @row1 I do have a laptop with windows 8.I do have a 3g dongle with an airtel connection but not which can broadcast wifi. Again recently I bought a nokia lumia 925 and am back with the same problem. Aaaagghhh...help.

Answer (score 10):

You currently cannot update it without a Wi-Fi connection. A few possible workarounds:

- Share your laptop's internet connection—most laptops should be able to share it via their Wi-Fi adaptor, if not you can always pick up a USB Wi-Fi dongle for a few dollars
- You mention that you also have a Lumia 925, setup a Wi-Fi hotspot on one of your phones to share your mobile connection
- Find a public Wi-Fi hotspot

Comment: Upvote for Sharing internet over WiFi on Lumia 925. Good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Mobile [reportedly might get rid](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-looks-set-remove-cellular-download-limits-store) of cellular download Limits for store downloads / updates.

Answer (score 0):

@Tridive

If you have laptop that means you have a wifi card, if you have dongle you have internet. what you can do is to share your internet using wifi ad-hoc connection.
Here is the manuel process to do that

1. Click on your Start Menu, then Control Panel, then Network and Sharing Center.
2. Now click on  Set up a new connection or network. When the new window opens, scroll down until you see Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer) network. Highlight that option by clicking once on it, then click the Next button.
3. You’ll now see a window that explains what an ad-hoc wireless network is

although you can make use of [Connectify](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-your-windows7-wifi-connection.htm) to make your life easier.

Answer (score -2):

You can download your update using internet sharing first you need android phone and turn on internet sharing and connect to the wifi i think this will work100% if you follow this step

Comment: As mentioned in previous answers any internet sharing would be sufficient. Just an other phone would be enough. There is no particular need for an Android. Also the OP already has an another Windows phone.